# Window Background VisualBrush DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, resourcedictionary

I have two projects, a resourcelibrary which holds a xaml file that simply has a visualbrush inside of it with a key called Theme. Inside this element is the Visual element and so on so forth. My main project is pulling in the xaml file like this

```
<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Visual={DynamicResource Theme}" />
</Window.Background
```

If I manually put the xaml code in this area it works perfect but I want the user to be able to flip through different xaml "themes". The problem is that right now because visualbrush in the xaml file has the key property the visual property won't convert to visualbrush... obviously... is there a way to set the visualbrush to the dynamicresource of the visualbrush element in the xaml file in resourcelibrary? This would give the effect I want to achieve. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Main Window

```
<Window x:Class="OASYS_View.MainWindow"
    Name="V_Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ResourceLibrary;assembly=ResourceLibrary"
    controls:ThemeManager.Theme="{Binding ElementName=themes, Path=SelectedItem}"
    Title="V" Height="1080" Width="1920"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Visual="{DynamicResource Theme}" />
</Window.Background>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="WindowFade" Completed="WindowFade_Completed">
                <DoubleAnimation  Name="WindowFadeAnimation"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="V_Window"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                        AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Unloaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="WindowFadeOut" Completed="WindowFadeOut_Completed">
                <DoubleAnimation  Name="WindowFadeOutAnimation"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="V_Window"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                        AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="themes" Width="150" Height="20" SelectionChanged="themes_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" />
    <controls:ProgressIndicator x:Name="Progress" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,50" Foreground="White" />
</Grid>
```

The Themed xaml file

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceLibrary">

<VisualBrush x:Key="Theme">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Viewbox Width="1920" Height="1080">
            <Canvas x:Name="PART_Canvas" Width="1920" Height="1080">
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Data="F1 M 1920.000,1079.906 L 0.000,1080.000 L 0.000,0.094 L 1920.000,0.000 L 1920.000,1079.906 Z">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="959.917,-1324.218" EndPoint="959.916,-55.456">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="#ff5090cd"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.66" Color="#ff5090cd"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.76" Color="#ff5090cd"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.95" Color="#ff287bbf"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="#ff0067b1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1.000,0.000,-0.000,-1.000,0.084,0.631" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Data="F1 M 1920.000,1080.789 L 0.001,1080.789 L 0.001,983.908 L 1920.000,983.908 L 1920.000,1080.789 Z">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="959.917,-1102.122" EndPoint="959.917,-988.308">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="#ff5090cd"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.87" Color="#ff5090cd"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="#ff5090cd"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1.000,0.000,-0.000,-1.000,0.084,0.631" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Path Fill="#ff0067b1" Data="F1 M 51.500,1042.869 C 51.500,1038.111 50.352,1034.229 48.053,1031.217 C 45.751,1028.203 42.730,1026.695 38.986,1026.695 C 35.227,1026.695 32.205,1028.203 29.921,1031.217 C 27.640,1034.229 26.498,1038.111 26.498,1042.869 C 26.498,1047.592 27.631,1051.420 29.899,1054.344 C 32.166,1057.268 35.195,1058.732 38.986,1058.732 C 42.764,1058.732 45.794,1057.268 48.075,1054.344 C 50.359,1051.420 51.500,1047.592 51.500,1042.869 Z M 56.825,1042.869 C 56.825,1047.979 55.179,1052.160 51.887,1055.408 C 48.595,1058.654 44.296,1060.277 38.986,1060.277 C 33.678,1060.277 29.382,1058.654 26.097,1055.408 C 22.813,1052.160 21.174,1047.979 21.174,1042.869 C 21.174,1037.744 22.824,1033.510 26.135,1030.166 C 29.441,1026.818 33.727,1025.148 38.986,1025.148 C 44.263,1025.148 48.556,1026.818 51.863,1030.166 C 55.172,1033.510 56.825,1037.744 56.825,1042.869 Z"/>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff0067b1" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Data="F1 M 21.224,1018.291 L 290.490,1018.291"/>
                            <Path Data="F1 M 135.245,1003.188 L 135.060,1009.395 L 137.035,1009.199 L 135.245,1003.188 Z M 130.846,1012.207 L 124.915,1008.137 L 129.871,1013.525 L 130.846,1012.207 Z M 137.423,1010.262 C 133.455,1010.262 130.202,1013.304 129.860,1017.178 L 144.985,1017.178 C 144.644,1013.304 141.391,1010.262 137.423,1010.262 Z M 133.857,1009.986 L 127.557,1002.258 L 132.096,1011.004 L 133.857,1009.986 Z M 145.892,1016.332 L 151.180,1014.025 L 145.482,1014.719 L 145.892,1016.332 Z M 142.287,999.391 L 138.402,1009.178 L 140.571,1009.801 L 142.287,999.391 Z M 128.842,1016.477 L 129.334,1014.762 L 118.275,1012.311 L 128.842,1016.477 Z M 143.382,1011.316 L 146.301,1004.479 L 141.899,1010.357 L 143.382,1011.316 Z M 144.091,1012.125 L 145.122,1013.596 L 151.921,1005.924 L 144.091,1012.125 Z">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" GradientOrigin="706.543,618.713" Center="706.543,618.713" RadiusX="5.469" RadiusY="5.469">
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="#ffffffff"/>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.43" Color="#ffcccccc"/>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="#ff999999"/>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="1.238,0.000,0.000,1.237,-737.613,251.618" />
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                            <Path Fill="#ff0067b1" Data="F1 M 77.781,1044.465 L 73.531,1032.145 L 68.950,1044.465 L 77.781,1044.465 Z M 92.457,1058.824 C 92.457,1059.277 92.327,1059.504 92.068,1059.504 C 90.953,1059.504 89.695,1059.453 88.289,1059.357 C 87.076,1059.262 86.045,1059.215 85.189,1059.215 C 84.203,1059.215 82.982,1059.262 81.530,1059.357 C 79.996,1059.453 78.689,1059.504 77.606,1059.504 C 77.351,1059.504 77.222,1059.283 77.222,1058.838 C 77.222,1058.396 77.318,1058.174 77.512,1058.174 C 78.947,1058.109 79.980,1057.920 80.611,1057.604 C 81.238,1057.289 81.553,1056.795 81.553,1056.133 C 81.553,1055.711 81.393,1055.037 81.070,1054.113 L 78.311,1046.012 L 68.371,1046.012 L 65.604,1053.508 C 65.248,1054.516 65.071,1055.291 65.071,1055.844 C 65.071,1057.266 66.377,1058.045 68.993,1058.174 C 69.187,1058.174 69.281,1058.396 69.281,1058.838 C 69.281,1059.283 69.152,1059.504 68.896,1059.504 C 67.928,1059.504 66.854,1059.453 65.676,1059.357 C 64.563,1059.262 63.570,1059.215 62.703,1059.215 C 62.008,1059.215 61.137,1059.262 60.090,1059.357 C 58.994,1059.453 58.060,1059.504 57.285,1059.504 C 57.042,1059.504 56.924,1059.303 56.924,1058.898 C 56.924,1058.449 57.107,1058.207 57.480,1058.174 C 58.818,1058.047 59.879,1057.676 60.662,1057.061 C 61.443,1056.449 62.256,1055.199 63.097,1053.314 L 74.422,1025.533 C 74.518,1025.277 74.745,1025.148 75.102,1025.148 C 75.486,1025.148 75.730,1025.270 75.826,1025.510 L 85.822,1053.314 C 86.388,1054.879 87.151,1056.031 88.109,1056.773 C 89.069,1057.512 90.359,1057.980 91.971,1058.174 C 92.295,1058.207 92.457,1058.424 92.457,1058.824 Z"/>
                            <Path Fill="#ff0067b1" Data="F1 M 115.325,1049.783 C 115.325,1052.994 114.372,1055.545 112.467,1057.439 C 110.561,1059.330 107.982,1060.277 104.736,1060.277 C 103.299,1060.277 101.580,1060.020 99.578,1059.504 C 97.750,1059.021 96.256,1058.779 95.093,1058.779 C 94.995,1056.039 94.803,1053.299 94.512,1050.561 C 94.512,1050.303 94.755,1050.174 95.238,1050.174 C 95.576,1050.174 95.787,1050.303 95.867,1050.561 C 96.740,1053.557 97.855,1055.670 99.215,1056.893 C 100.570,1058.117 102.473,1058.732 104.923,1058.732 C 106.874,1058.732 108.386,1058.166 109.459,1057.039 C 110.530,1055.910 111.064,1054.330 111.064,1052.301 C 111.064,1050.994 110.598,1049.781 109.663,1048.660 C 108.728,1047.537 106.734,1046.094 103.686,1044.320 C 100.184,1042.305 97.893,1040.596 96.811,1039.193 C 95.730,1037.791 95.191,1036.236 95.191,1034.527 C 95.191,1031.902 96.163,1029.682 98.109,1027.869 C 100.057,1026.055 102.525,1025.148 105.513,1025.148 C 106.645,1025.148 107.946,1025.301 109.414,1025.607 C 110.787,1025.883 111.977,1026.020 112.977,1026.020 C 113.171,1028.854 113.429,1031.354 113.752,1033.512 C 113.752,1033.770 113.544,1033.902 113.124,1033.902 C 112.674,1033.902 112.422,1033.770 112.375,1033.512 C 111.840,1031.096 111.029,1029.355 109.947,1028.289 C 108.867,1027.229 107.368,1026.695 105.457,1026.695 C 103.641,1026.695 102.197,1027.229 101.127,1028.289 C 100.057,1029.355 99.522,1030.791 99.522,1032.596 C 99.522,1033.736 99.971,1034.828 100.871,1035.869 C 101.770,1036.908 103.714,1038.301 106.707,1040.041 C 110.253,1042.104 112.574,1043.828 113.676,1045.215 C 114.774,1046.600 115.325,1048.123 115.325,1049.783 Z"/>
                            <Path Fill="#ff0067b1" Data="F1 M 154.821,1026.537 C 154.821,1026.713 154.766,1026.865 154.652,1027.002 C 154.539,1027.133 154.418,1027.205 154.289,1027.205 C 152.691,1027.379 151.486,1027.711 150.671,1028.203 C 149.855,1028.688 148.893,1029.740 147.779,1031.361 L 138.728,1044.369 L 138.728,1054.090 C 138.728,1055.188 138.820,1055.959 139.006,1056.408 C 139.193,1056.859 139.619,1057.229 140.291,1057.508 C 140.959,1057.793 141.979,1058.014 143.350,1058.174 C 143.609,1058.207 143.738,1058.424 143.738,1058.824 C 143.738,1059.277 143.609,1059.504 143.350,1059.504 C 142.271,1059.504 141.051,1059.453 139.695,1059.357 C 138.387,1059.262 137.238,1059.215 136.248,1059.215 C 135.273,1059.215 134.076,1059.262 132.652,1059.357 C 131.152,1059.453 129.862,1059.504 128.782,1059.504 C 128.523,1059.504 128.395,1059.277 128.395,1058.824 C 128.395,1058.424 128.523,1058.207 128.782,1058.174 C 130.734,1057.949 132.061,1057.586 132.762,1057.086 C 133.463,1056.588 133.814,1055.590 133.814,1054.090 L 133.814,1044.465 L 125.443,1031.336 C 124.297,1029.715 123.289,1028.662 122.418,1028.176 C 121.545,1027.689 120.375,1027.365 118.908,1027.205 C 118.649,1027.205 118.520,1026.980 118.520,1026.537 C 118.520,1026.094 118.649,1025.873 118.908,1025.873 C 119.663,1025.873 120.693,1025.920 122.000,1026.020 C 123.418,1026.115 124.563,1026.164 125.430,1026.164 C 126.254,1026.164 127.388,1026.115 128.838,1026.020 C 130.531,1025.920 131.941,1025.873 133.070,1025.873 C 133.328,1025.873 133.459,1026.094 133.459,1026.537 C 133.459,1026.980 133.328,1027.205 133.070,1027.205 C 130.975,1027.494 129.926,1028.047 129.926,1028.861 C 129.926,1029.512 130.257,1030.350 130.916,1031.373 L 137.921,1042.266 L 145.232,1031.336 C 145.752,1030.572 146.010,1029.908 146.010,1029.344 C 146.010,1028.725 145.725,1028.260 145.148,1027.945 C 144.576,1027.629 143.604,1027.379 142.234,1027.205 C 142.039,1027.205 141.941,1026.980 141.941,1026.537 C 141.941,1026.094 142.072,1025.873 142.329,1025.873 C 143.283,1025.873 144.444,1025.920 145.816,1026.020 C 147.153,1026.115 148.268,1026.164 149.155,1026.164 C 149.980,1026.164 150.852,1026.115 151.771,1026.020 C 152.707,1025.920 153.594,1025.873 154.436,1025.873 C 154.693,1025.873 154.821,1026.094 154.821,1026.537 Z"/>
                            <Path Fill="#ff0067b1" Data="F1 M 177.619,1049.783 C 177.619,1052.994 176.666,1055.545 174.762,1057.439 C 172.855,1059.330 170.278,1060.277 167.031,1060.277 C 165.594,1060.277 163.875,1060.020 161.871,1059.504 C 160.046,1059.021 158.551,1058.779 157.389,1058.779 C 157.291,1056.039 157.098,1053.299 156.807,1050.561 C 156.807,1050.303 157.048,1050.174 157.533,1050.174 C 157.872,1050.174 158.081,1050.303 158.162,1050.561 C 159.035,1053.557 160.148,1055.670 161.506,1056.893 C 162.863,1058.117 164.767,1058.732 167.219,1058.732 C 169.169,1058.732 170.682,1058.166 171.753,1057.039 C 172.823,1055.910 173.360,1054.330 173.360,1052.301 C 173.360,1050.994 172.893,1049.781 171.957,1048.660 C 171.021,1047.537 169.029,1046.094 165.979,1044.320 C 162.480,1042.305 160.188,1040.596 159.105,1039.193 C 158.025,1037.791 157.482,1036.236 157.482,1034.527 C 157.482,1031.902 158.459,1029.682 160.403,1027.869 C 162.352,1026.055 164.819,1025.148 167.809,1025.148 C 168.939,1025.148 170.238,1025.301 171.709,1025.607 C 173.082,1025.883 174.268,1026.020 175.271,1026.020 C 175.466,1028.854 175.725,1031.354 176.048,1033.512 C 176.048,1033.770 175.836,1033.902 175.418,1033.902 C 174.965,1033.902 174.717,1033.770 174.666,1033.512 C 174.135,1031.096 173.325,1029.355 172.244,1028.289 C 171.158,1027.229 169.661,1026.695 167.748,1026.695 C 165.935,1026.695 164.492,1027.229 163.422,1028.289 C 162.352,1029.355 161.817,1030.791 161.817,1032.596 C 161.817,1033.736 162.266,1034.828 163.163,1035.869 C 164.061,1036.908 166.010,1038.301 169.002,1040.041 C 172.547,1042.104 174.868,1043.828 175.971,1045.215 C 177.070,1046.600 177.619,1048.123 177.619,1049.783 Z"/>
                            <Path StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#ff0067b1" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Data="F1 M 21.224,1066.850 L 290.490,1066.850"/>
                            <Canvas>
                                <Path Opacity="0.5" Fill="#ff4b4d4d" Data="F1 M 199.003,1053.682 L 199.088,1053.682 L 208.492,1026.553 L 210.516,1026.553 L 198.961,1059.369 L 187.532,1026.553 L 189.557,1026.553 L 199.003,1053.682 Z"/>
                                <Path Opacity="0.5" Fill="#ff4b4d4d" Data="F1 M 216.168,1058.316 L 214.143,1058.316 L 214.143,1026.553 L 216.168,1026.553 L 216.168,1058.316 Z"/>
                                <Path Opacity="0.5" Fill="#ff4b4d4d" Data="F1 M 225.024,1028.445 L 225.024,1039.990 L 237.844,1039.990 L 237.844,1041.887 L 225.024,1041.887 L 225.024,1056.420 L 238.181,1056.420 L 238.181,1058.316 L 223.000,1058.316 L 223.000,1026.553 L 238.181,1026.553 L 238.181,1028.445 L 225.024,1028.445 Z"/>
                                <Path Opacity="0.5" Fill="#ff4b4d4d" Data="F1 M 252.436,1053.850 L 264.327,1024.949 L 276.219,1053.850 L 285.033,1026.553 L 287.057,1026.553 L 276.347,1059.369 L 264.201,1030.004 L 252.098,1059.369 L 241.471,1026.553 L 243.495,1026.553 L 252.436,1053.850 Z"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Canvas>
                </Canvas>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You'll see that VisualBrush has the keyname but in mainwindow.background I need to bind to visual property of visualbrush.

{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.VisualBrush' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Visual'."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Try this

```
<Window Background="{DynamicResource Theme}"
        ...>
```

Comment: I'm using merged dictionaries in my code behind and that works ok... I'll update my question with more code to display whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your resource dictionary file to the Window's resources and then point to the visual in the background.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Visual="{VisualKey}"/>
  </Window.Background>
</Window>
```

Comment: This would still pose the same issue, edited question above to describe the issue better.